# Java WatchService misses events, files

Tags: java, filesystemwatcher, watchservice

I want to monitor a folder for newly created subfolders for specific .csv files using Java WatchService API (Windows 7 x64, Java 8). I expect the final application like this: folders\files will be created somewhere else and loaded into a cloud (e.g. GDrive). From there I will synchronize them with a local folder (using stock software). This local folder I want to monitor and process files within minutes after they appear. Also very important is not to miss any new files.

I use WatchService as in many tutorials and questions here, but still it behaves strangely.

- When the folder (already with files) is created it is both CREATED and MODIFIED - thus two events for a folder. I can live with it, but it sometimes misses files in it completely. (I suppose, files are copied so fast, that they are there even before this new folder is registered and monitored).
- When I copy several folders with files at once (F1,F2,F3) then it:
  registers F1, detects modified files in F1, processes them, registers F2, registers F3.
  Again, the files in the last two folders are not detected anyhow.

Here is a simplified code that I use. I am looking for a cause of this issues and how to make it more robust.
I can cut and paste all files from every new folder and hope then it will detect them, but this is the worst case solution.

More general question - what happens between ws.take() and ws.pollEvents() and ws.reset()? Are there blind-moments, when events are not registered?

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    // SET UP LOGGER AND CONFIG VARIABLES HERE

    // CREATE AN OBJECT AND DEFINE AN ABSTRACT startListening()
    WatchServiceClass wsc = new WatchServiceClass() {
       public void startListening(WatchService watchService) {
        while (true) {
            WatchKey queuedKey = watchService.take();
            // DOESNT HELP: Thread.sleep(1000);
            List<WatchEvent<?>> events = queuedKey.pollEvents();
            for (WatchEvent<?> watchEvent : events) {
                if (watchEvent.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.OVERFLOW) {
                    continue;
                }
                String action // create, modify or delete 
                String fileName // self explanatory
                String fullPath
                String fullPathParent


                if (action.equals("create")) { // TRACK NEW FOLDERS
                    registerDir(Paths.get(fullPath), watchService);
                }

                if (new File(fullPath).isDirectory()) {
                    continue; // NOT DOING ANYTHING WITH DIRECTORIES
                } 
                // IF HERE, THEN THIS IS THE FILE, DO SOMETHING
                // TAKES SEVERAL MINUTES
            }

            if (!queuedKey.reset()) {
                keyPathMap.remove(queuedKey);
            }
            if (keyPathMap.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    };
     // END OF startListening() METHOD DEFINITION  

    while (true) { // MAIN INFINITE LOOP
      try (WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()) {
        wsc.registerDir(Paths.get(DATA_DIR), watchService); 
        wsc.startListening(watchService);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    }
```